# How to add another same chart but with different data?

Tags: highcharts

I create chart using HighCharts and I copy some example from official site, [I havesomething exactly like this jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/) How to add on the same page another same chart with different data?
I'm looking on google and here for some example but can't find something matching my example.

```
$(function () {

var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
    data = [{
        y: 56.33,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0', 'MSIE 10.0', 'MSIE 11.0'],
            data: [1.06, 0.5, 17.2, 8.11, 5.33, 24.13],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        y: 10.38,
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Firefox versions',
            categories: ['Firefox v31', 'Firefox v32', 'Firefox v33', 'Firefox v35', 'Firefox v36', 'Firefox v37', 'Firefox v38'],
            data: [0.33, 0.15, 0.22, 1.27, 2.76, 2.32, 2.31, 1.02],
            color: colors[1]
        }
    }, {
        y: 24.03,
        color: colors[2],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Chrome versions',
            categories: ['Chrome v30.0', 'Chrome v31.0', 'Chrome v32.0', 'Chrome v33.0', 'Chrome v34.0',
                'Chrome v35.0', 'Chrome v36.0', 'Chrome v37.0', 'Chrome v38.0', 'Chrome v39.0', 'Chrome v40.0', 'Chrome v41.0', 'Chrome v42.0', 'Chrome v43.0'
                ],
            data: [0.14, 1.24, 0.55, 0.19, 0.14, 0.85, 2.53, 0.38, 0.6, 2.96, 5, 4.32, 3.68, 1.45],
            color: colors[2]
        }
    }, {
        y: 4.77,
        color: colors[3],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari v5.0', 'Safari v5.1', 'Safari v6.1', 'Safari v6.2', 'Safari v7.0', 'Safari v7.1', 'Safari v8.0'],
            data: [0.3, 0.42, 0.29, 0.17, 0.26, 0.77, 2.56],
            color: colors[3]
        }
    }, {
        y: 0.91,
        color: colors[4],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Opera versions',
            categories: ['Opera v12.x', 'Opera v27', 'Opera v28', 'Opera v29'],
            data: [0.34, 0.17, 0.24, 0.16],
            color: colors[4]
        }
    }, {
        y: 0.2,
        color: colors[5],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            categories: [],
            data: [],
            color: colors[5]
        }
    }],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;


// Build the data arrays
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
        brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com/">netmarketshare.com</a>'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: browserData,
        size: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: '#ffffff',
            distance: -30
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

By setting a second container and add 3 new arrays: Data2, browserData2 and versionsData2, don't forget to add the last two arrays (browserData2 and versionsData2) to the series option in the second container:

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData2,
            size: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: '#ffffff',
                distance: -30
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData2,
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                }
            }
        }]
```

Please check the following example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/ty00kro4/)):

```
$(function () {

    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
        data = [{
            y: 56.33,
            color: colors[0],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'MSIE versions',
                categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0', 'MSIE 10.0', 'MSIE 11.0'],
                data: [1.06, 0.5, 17.2, 8.11, 5.33, 24.13],
                color: colors[0]
            }
        }, {
            y: 10.38,
            color: colors[1],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Firefox versions',
                categories: ['Firefox v31', 'Firefox v32', 'Firefox v33', 'Firefox v35', 'Firefox v36', 'Firefox v37', 'Firefox v38'],
                data: [0.33, 0.15, 0.22, 1.27, 2.76, 2.32, 2.31, 1.02],
                color: colors[1]
            }
        }, {
            y: 24.03,
            color: colors[2],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Chrome versions',
                categories: ['Chrome v30.0', 'Chrome v31.0', 'Chrome v32.0', 'Chrome v33.0', 'Chrome v34.0',
                    'Chrome v35.0', 'Chrome v36.0', 'Chrome v37.0', 'Chrome v38.0', 'Chrome v39.0', 'Chrome v40.0', 'Chrome v41.0', 'Chrome v42.0', 'Chrome v43.0'
                    ],
                data: [0.14, 1.24, 0.55, 0.19, 0.14, 0.85, 2.53, 0.38, 0.6, 2.96, 5, 4.32, 3.68, 1.45],
                color: colors[2]
            }
        }, {
            y: 4.77,
            color: colors[3],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Safari versions',
                categories: ['Safari v5.0', 'Safari v5.1', 'Safari v6.1', 'Safari v6.2', 'Safari v7.0', 'Safari v7.1', 'Safari v8.0'],
                data: [0.3, 0.42, 0.29, 0.17, 0.26, 0.77, 2.56],
                color: colors[3]
            }
        }, {
            y: 0.91,
            color: colors[4],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Opera versions',
                categories: ['Opera v12.x', 'Opera v27', 'Opera v28', 'Opera v29'],
                data: [0.34, 0.17, 0.24, 0.16],
                color: colors[4]
            }
        }, {
            y: 0.2,
            color: colors[5],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                categories: [],
                data: [],
                color: colors[5]
            }
        }],

                categories2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        data2 = [{
            y: 56.33,
            color: colors[0],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'MSIE versions',
                categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0', 'MSIE 10.0', 'MSIE 11.0'],
                data: [1.06, 0.5, 17.2, 8.11, 5.33, 24.13],
                color: colors[0]
            }
        }, {
            y: 10.38,
            color: colors[1],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Firefox versions',
                categories: ['F7', 'F6', 'F5', 'F4', 'F3', 'F2', 'F1'],
                data: [0.33, 0.15, 0.22, 1.27, 2.76, 2.32, 2.31, 1.02],
                color: colors[1]
            }
        }, {
            y: 24.03,
            color: colors[2],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Chrome versions',
                categories: ['Cn', 'Cm', 'Cj', 'Ct', 'Cb',
                    'Cc', 'Cf', 'Cy', 'Ct', 'Cr', 'Cr', 'Ce', 'Cw', 'Cq'
                    ],
                data: [0.14, 1.24, 0.55, 0.19, 0.14, 0.85, 2.53, 0.38, 0.6, 2.96, 5, 4.32, 3.68, 1.45],
                color: colors[2]
            }
        }, {
            y: 4.77,
            color: colors[3],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Safari versions',
                categories: ['S7', 'S6', 'S5', 'S4', 'S3', 'S2', 'S1'],
                data: [0.3, 0.42, 0.29, 0.17, 0.26, 0.77, 2.56],
                color: colors[3]
            }
        }, {
            y: 0.91,
            color: colors[4],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Opera versions',
                categories: ['O1', 'O2', 'O3', 'O4'],
                data: [0.34, 0.17, 0.24, 0.16],
                color: colors[4]
            }
        }, {
            y: 0.2,
            color: colors[5],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                categories: [],
                data: [],
                color: colors[5]
            }
        }],
        browserData = [],
        versionsData = [],
        browserData2 = [],
        versionsData2 = [],
        i,
        j,
        dataLen = data.length,
        dataLen2 = data2.length,
        drillDataLen,
        brightness;


    // Build the data arrays
    for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

        // add browser data
        browserData.push({
            name: categories[i],
            y: data[i].y,
            color: data[i].color
        });

        // add version data
        drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
        for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
            brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
            versionsData.push({
                name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
            });
        }
    }
        // Build the data arrays
    for (i = 0; i < dataLen2; i += 1) {

        // add browser data
        browserData2.push({
            name: categories2[i],
            y: data2[i].y,
            color: data2[i].color
        });

        // add version data
        drillDataLen = data2[i].drilldown.data.length;
        for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
            brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
            versionsData2.push({
                name: data2[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                y: data2[i].drilldown.data[j],
                color: Highcharts.Color(data2[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
            });
        }
    }

    // Create the chart
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com/">netmarketshare.com</a>'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                center: ['50%', '50%']
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData,
            size: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: '#ffffff',
                distance: -30
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData,
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                }
            }
        }]
    });
        $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Second Chart'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com/">netmarketshare.com</a>'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                center: ['50%', '50%']
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: browserData2,
            size: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: '#ffffff',
                distance: -30
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: versionsData2,
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need 3 charts you can copy-paste the initialization and just change the data and container name.

Or you can make a function, that populate a chart by given data and container name. Something like this:

```
function populateChart(renderTo,data,title) {
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: renderTo,
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: title
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: data,
        stack: 'male'
    }]
});
}
```

And then just call it when needed:

```
 $(function(){
    populateChart('container1',[5, 3, 4, 7, 2],'Title 1');
    populateChart('container2',[3, 4, 4, 2, 5],'Title 2');
    populateChart('container3',[2, 5, 6, 2, 1],'Title 3');
});
```

You can check my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulson/gg3f9623/)